# How to model java class after nested Json response

Tags: java, json, parsing, gson, restful-authentication

How can I model a java object after a nested json response. I'm trying to use GSON library from google in order to parse this response, so I want to go from json string to java

**Example**

**Json response**

```
{
  "iamTicket": {
    "ticket": "W1-104-Q36w4qw0hdklirrgtuioqbp",
    "userId": "13748569064",
    "userIdPseudonym": null,
    "agentId": "839298462",
    "realmId": null,
    "authenticationLevel": "20",
    "identityAssuranceLevel": null,
    "namespaceId": "50000003",
    "role": [],
    "access": "",
    "scoped": null,
    "authTime": null
  },
  "userExtInfo": {
    "user": {
      "userId": null,
      "username": null,
      "userType": null,
      "namespaceId": null,
      "password": null,
      "securityLevel": null,
      "challengeQuestionAnswer": [],
      "umRole": null,
      "credentialStatus": null,
      "fullName": [],
      "displayName": [],
      "characteristics": null,
      "address": [],
      "phone": [
        {
          "parentId": null,
          "debugInfo": null,
          "id": null,
          "type": "MOBILE",
          "primary": null,
          "phoneNumber": "7603042083",
          "status": null
        }
      ],
      "email": {
        "id": null,
        "type": null,
        "primary": null,
        "address": "mhaddad@apple.com",
        "status": null
      },
      "alternateEmail": [],
      "i18NAttribute": null,
      "creditCard": [],
      "preferredCCId": null,
      "isRecoveryInfoSet": null,
      "taxIdentifier": []
    },
    "authOfferingUsage": null,
    "realmIds": [],
    "grant": [],
    "taxStatus": []
  },
  "needContactInfoUpdate": false,
  "altAuthInfoSet": true,
  "action": "CHALLENGE",
  "riskLevel": "MED"
}
```

Here is the Java Object I've created after for the response:

**IUSAuth.java**

```
package com.apple.confedential.internal.helper;

public class IUSAuth { 

    public IUSAuth() {}

    IAMTicket iamTicket;
    UserExtInfo userExtInfo;
    Boolean needContactInfoUpdate;
    Boolean altAuthInfoSet;
    String action;
    String riskLevel;

    public static class IAMTicket {
        String ticket; 
        String userId; 
        Integer userIdPseudonym; 
        String agentId; 
        String realmId; 
        String authenticationLevel; 
        Integer identityAssuranceLevel; 
        String namespaceId; 
        String[] role; 
        String access; 
        Integer scoped; 
        Integer authTime; 

        public String getTicket() {
            return ticket;
        }
        public void setTicket(String ticket) {
            this.ticket = ticket;
        }
        public String getUserId() {
            return userId;
        }
        public void setUserId(String userId) {
            this.userId = userId;
        }
        public Integer getUserIdPseudonym() {
            return userIdPseudonym;
        }
        public void setUserIdPseudonym(Integer userIdPseudonym) {
            this.userIdPseudonym = userIdPseudonym;
        }
        public String getAgentId() {
            return agentId;
        }
        public void setAgentId(String agentId) {
            this.agentId = agentId;
        }
        public String getRealmId() {
            return realmId;
        }
        public void setRealmId(String realmId) {
            this.realmId = realmId;
        }
        public String getAuthenticationLevel() {
            return authenticationLevel;
        }
        public void setAuthenticationLevel(String authenticationLevel) {
            this.authenticationLevel = authenticationLevel;
        }
        public Integer getIdentityAssuranceLevel() {
            return identityAssuranceLevel;
        }
        public void setIdentityAssuranceLevel(Integer identityAssuranceLevel) {
            this.identityAssuranceLevel = identityAssuranceLevel;
        }
        public String getNamespaceId() {
            return namespaceId;
        }
        public void setNamespaceId(String namespaceId) {
            this.namespaceId = namespaceId;
        }
        public String[] getRole() {
            return role;
        }
        public void setRole(String[] role) { 
            this.role = role;
        }
        public String getAccess() { 
            return access;
        }
        public void setAccess(String access) {
            this.access = access;
        }
        public Integer getScoped() {
            return scoped;
        }
        public void setScoped(Integer scoped) {
            this.scoped = scoped;
        }
        public Integer getAuthTime() {
            return authTime;
        }
        public void setAuthTime(Integer authTime) {
            this.authTime = authTime;
        }
    }

    public static class UserExtInfo {

        User user;
        String authOfferingUsage;
        RealmIds[] realmIds;
        Grant[] grant;
        TaxStatus[] taxStatus;

        public static class User{


            String userId;
            String username;
            String userType;
            String namespaceId;
            String password;
            String securityLevel;
            String[] challengeQuestionAnswer;
            String umRole;
            String credentialStatus;
            String[] fullName;
            String[] displayName;
            String characteristics;
            String[] address;
            Phone phone; 
            Email email;
            AlternateEmail[] alternateEmail;
            String i18NAttribute;
            String[] creditCard;
            String preferredCCId;
            String isRecoveryInfoSet;
            String taxIdentifier;

            public static class AlternateEmail {

            }

            public static class Email {
                String id;
                String type;
                String primary;
                String address;
                String status;
            }

            public static class Phone {
                String parentId;
                String debugInfo;
                String id;
                String type;
                String primary;
                String phoneNumber;
                String status;
                public String getParentId() {
                    return parentId;
                }
                public void setParentId(String parentId) {
                    this.parentId = parentId;
                }
                public String getDebugInfo() {
                    return debugInfo;
                }
                public void setDebugInfo(String debugInfo) {
                    this.debugInfo = debugInfo;
                }
                public String getId() {
                    return id;
                }
                public void setId(String id) {
                    this.id = id;
                }
                public String getType() {
                    return type;
                }
                public void setType(String type) {
                    this.type = type;
                }
                public String getPrimary() {
                    return primary;
                }
                public void setPrimary(String primary) {
                    this.primary = primary;
                }
                public String getPhoneNumber() {
                    return phoneNumber;
                }
                public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
                    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
                }
                public String getStatus() {
                    return status;
                }
                public void setStatus(String status) {
                    this.status = status;
                }



            }

            public String getUserId() {
                return userId;
            }

            public void setUserId(String userId) {
                this.userId = userId;
            }

            public String getUsername() {
                return username;
            }

            public void setUsername(String username) {
                this.username = username;
            }

            public String getUserType() {
                return userType;
            }

            public void setUserType(String userType) {
                this.userType = userType;
            }

            public String getNamespaceId() {
                return namespaceId;
            }

            public void setNamespaceId(String namespaceId) {
                this.namespaceId = namespaceId;
            }

            public String getPassword() {
                return password;
            }

            public void setPassword(String password) {
                this.password = password;
            }

            public String getSecurityLevel() {
                return securityLevel;
            }

            public void setSecurityLevel(String securityLevel) {
                this.securityLevel = securityLevel;
            }

            public String[] getChallengeQuestionAnswer() {
                return challengeQuestionAnswer;
            }

            public void setChallengeQuestionAnswer(String[] challengeQuestionAnswer) {
                this.challengeQuestionAnswer = challengeQuestionAnswer;
            }

            public String getUmRole() {
                return umRole;
            }

            public void setUmRole(String umRole) {
                this.umRole = umRole;
            }

            public String getCredentialStatus() {
                return credentialStatus;
            }

            public void setCredentialStatus(String credentialStatus) {
                this.credentialStatus = credentialStatus;
            }

            public String[] getFullName() {
                return fullName;
            }

            public void setFullName(String[] fullName) {
                this.fullName = fullName;
            }

            public String[] getDisplayName() {
                return displayName;
            }

            public void setDisplayName(String[] displayName) {
                this.displayName = displayName;
            }

            public String getCharacteristics() {
                return characteristics;
            }

            public void setCharacteristics(String characteristics) {
                this.characteristics = characteristics;
            }

            public String[] getAddress() {
                return address;
            }

            public void setAddress(String[] address) {
                this.address = address;
            }

            public Phone getPhone() {
                return phone;
            }

            public void setPhone(Phone phone) {
                this.phone = phone;
            }
        }

        public static class RealmIds{

        }

        public static class Grant{

        }

        public static class TaxStatus{

        }


        public User getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
            this.user = user;
        }

        public String getAuthOfferingUsage() {
            return authOfferingUsage;
        }

        public void setAuthOfferingUsage(String authOfferingUsage) {
            this.authOfferingUsage = authOfferingUsage;
        }

        public RealmIds[] getRealmIds() {
            return realmIds;
        }

        public void setRealmIds(RealmIds[] realmIds) {
            this.realmIds = realmIds;
        }

        public Grant[] getGrant() {
            return grant;
        }

        public void setGrant(Grant[] grant) {
            this.grant = grant;
        }

        public TaxStatus[] getTaxStatus() {
            return taxStatus;
        }

        public void setTaxStatus(TaxStatus[] taxStatus) {
            this.taxStatus = taxStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I want to use GSON library from google to parse to get the ticket data:

```
public String parseIUSResponse(String jsonResponse) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    IUSAuth response = gson.fromJson(jsonResponse, IUSAuth.class);

    // How to get ticket from iamticket object??

    return "";

}
```

Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Wow... you are way off... Start with making your inner objects.

Comment: I knew something was wrong...Can you please show an example how?

Comment: First of all, you need to break down your JSON string into its corresponding objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think in terms of objects. There are two objects in that JSON string. All the other properties are inner objects or properties.

```
package com.apple.internal.helper;

public class IUSAuth {

IAMTicket iamTicket;
UserExtInfo userExtInfo;


public IUSAuth() {}

public class IAMTicket {
// ADD ALL YOUR IAMTicket Properties Here
String ticket;
}

public class UserExtInfo{
// ADD ALL YOUR USEREXTINFO Properties here
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks shinjw, I'm coming from absolute C embedded systems background, still not entirely comfortable with java

Comment: Wow, thanks for following up. I just finished creating the Java class model. I have updated my original post with this model, however in my top level when I attempt to convert the Json to Java, it isn't working...

Comment: Change your String[] to ArrayList<String>